# NSIS Change Header Image Based on Language Selection

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to create an installer.  How can I change the header image (MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP) based on the users language selection at install?

Comment: Can you put an explanation of what you have already tired?

Comment: The last thing I tried was calling GetDlgItem $mui.Header.Image in the .onInit but I don't know how to include the other image in the installer package.  Forgive me if I am not using the correct terminology.  I'm new to NSIS.

Comment: No HWNDs are valid in .onInit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
...
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE Swedish

Function .onInit
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

Function myGUIInit
    InitPluginsDir
    ${If} ${LANG_ENGLISH} = $Language
        File "/oname=$PluginsDir\langspecifichdr.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\orange.bmp"
    ${Else}
        File "/oname=$PluginsDir\langspecifichdr.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\win.bmp"
    ${EndIf}
    SetBrandingImage /IMGID=1046 "$PluginsDir\langspecifichdr.bmp"
FunctionEnd
```